# Cookies must be enabled in your browser [Python Requests]

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

So I'm trying to log into my hotmail account via python and keep getting this response on the page when I make this request

```
r = requests.post('https://login.live.com', auth=('Email', 'Pass'),verify=False)

Cookies must be allowed

Your browser is currently set to block cookies. Your browser must allow cookies before you can use a Microsoft account.

Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell Microsoft sites and services when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, see online help in your web browser.
```

I would also like to mention that I am trying to httpPOST to this webpage because I would rather handle the cookies in the response and access other pages of my microsoft profile (rather than just accessing my email via the smtp server)

Thanks!

Edit :

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://login.live.com',verify=False)
r = s.post('https://login.live.com', auth=('user', 'pass'),verify=False)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `requests.Session` to persist a session (with cookies included):

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://login.live.com')
cookies = dict(res.cookies)
res = s.post('https://login.live.com', 
    auth=('Email', 'Password'),
    verify=False, 
    cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Super weird because I print the text of the post and it says cookies must be enabled (same message). But it does give me a cookie in my cookie jar, extremely weird I'll keep experimenting with session though thanks!

Comment: Presumably you would have to first call `s.get()`, to give the server a chance to set the cookies.

Comment: Hmm, I understand what you mean. Still coming out weird though I updated the code im currently using on the bottom of the question. Sorry for being so bad at this lol, never had this error at all before.

Comment: @k9b, use the `cookies` argument in your post message, i.e.:

`s.post('https://login.live.com', auth=('Email', 'Pass'),verify=False, cookies={'my': 'cookies'})`

Comment: I actually dont think its anything I'm doing wrong. I just dont think microsoft wants me logging in via http request and its just giving me this as a default error lol. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Yea I tried your code in addition adding a verify=False to the "GET" and then print res.text and still get the cookies error :) I think its just microsoft lol

Comment: @leongold thanks a lot. When trying the code, I got in the response the following `Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript`. How can javascript enabled?