# Python requests ConnectionError

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to login to this [website](http://www.voobly.com/login). With the following piece of code:

```
import requests

values = {'password': 'somepass', 'username': 'someusername'}
login_url = "http://voobly.com/login"

session_requests = requests.session()
r = session_requests.post(login_url, data=values,
                          headers=dict(referer=login_url))
```

And this is the form to login into the website.

```
<form action="/login/auth" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" value="">
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="inputfield">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login-button">
</form>
```

Well, when I run the code I get this error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.voobly.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /login
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7cca037be0>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

How I can solve this? I can login in the browser but I can't login throught python code.

Comment: You can try with `mechanize` or `selenium`

Comment: I removed the answer as it too much work to do with requests. It is better to switch to mechanize

Comment: Ok, but I think that mechanize works only on python 2. I'm working with python 3. Should I try with selenium then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending POST request to a wrong URL, it should be `http://www.voobly.com/login/auth`:

[image]

```
import requests

values = {'password': 'somepass', 'username': 'someusername'}
login_url = "http://www.voobly.com/login/auth"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)', 
           ... # more...
           'Referer': 'http://www.voobly.com/login'}

session_requests = requests.session()
r = session_requests.post(login_url, data=values,
                          headers=headers)
```

Comment: You're right, but now I have another problem. "You must have cookies enabled to visit this site" that is the response. How I enable cookies on requests.Session?

Comment: I try to set cookie trought Set-Cookie header, with **r = session_requests.get(main_url)**. I obtain this on r.headers['Set-Cookie'] : 'vbly_test=1; expires=Mon, 06-Mar-2017 17:21:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.voobly.com; httponly'.

Comment: Ok, this is the solution for this cookie issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516483/cookies-must-be-enabled-in-your-browser-python-requests