# Why i can't enable cookies with request, even before they was turned on and worked fine [python3 , requests]

Tags: python-3.x, request, session-cookies

Not so far ago I decided to expand my vocabulary, and find a great website to do that - Memrise. I thought it is great because you can create a new set of words by yourself and learn exactly, what you need. But then a problem appeared - adding new words is taking too many time, so I decided to create a python script that will automatically add words from dictionary (for example txt file that looks like word-translation) to the website. For that goal, I used a request library. First thing I need to do - is to login to the website. Next thig, I need to do is to go the edit page, and set a post request with data about the word, that looks  so:

```
columns {"1":"hi","2":"hello"}
level_id     8301249
```

Where the word is in columns section, and level id - is an id of course. But when I tried to send it, I get a response, that cookies are disabled in your browser. 
I tried to send a post request as written here, [Cookies must be enabled in your browser [Python Requests]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516483/cookies-must-be-enabled-in-your-browser-python-requests), but that doesn't help
Also, I added a `request.Session()`, object, but that doesn't help too. I thought the problem can be reasoned because of incomplete headers I send with the request, so I added a User-agent, but that doesn't help too. Maybe this error in some way connected with `ajax` request? I saw, that one of the solutions is to use mechanize, but is there a way to do such a job with python's `requests` library. Also, I can't understand why I was able to login to the webpage, (need cookies in that process too) but can't send a post request? 
Here is my code:

```
import requests

session_requests = requests.Session()
session_requests.headers.update({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64...) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'})

#url of login page
login_url = "https://www.memrise.com/login/"

session_requests.get(login_url)
#one of three required parameters sending by login request ( 1 - username , 2 - password , 3 - csrftoken )
csrftoken = session_requests.cookies["csrftoken"]

#data for login request
data = {
    "username": "example@email.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken
}


#url of course i want add words to
edit_course_url = 'https://www.memrise.com/course/2253971/example-course/edit/#l_8308032'
#login post request
loged_in = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = data,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)
#trying to enable cookies
edit = session_requests.get(edit_course_url)
cookies = dict(edit.cookies)
cookies['CSRFToken'] = cookies.pop('csrftoken')



#structure of new word , should be send
new_word = {
    'columns':{"1":"hi","2":"ro"},
    'level_id':'8308032'
}


add_word = session_requests.post(
    #Request URL
    'https://www.memrise.com/ajax/level/thing/add/',
    data=new_word,
    #reference to the site taken from post request , sended from browser
    headers =dict(referer='https://www.memrise.com/course/2253971/example-course/edit/'),
    cookies = cookies
)

print(loged_in.status_code , loged_in.reason)
print(add_word.status_code , add_word.reason

)
```